# Export SQL Database Changes Made Over Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're setting up a test environment to run automated tests against.

We wanted to have a clean environment, so everytime code is checked in we blow away the database, create a new one from scratch, and populate it with data from a .sql script.

What I would like, since I'm lazy, is a way for someone to make changes using the UI that change things in the database, and then just export the changes that were made into a .sql script that we can add to the base script when the db is created.

Does anybody know if there is a way to start detecting any changes made to the db and export those into a sql script?

I've done a basic search for this and if it exists I must not be searching the right terms. Thanks :)

Comment: Not ideal or perfect: `Select * from sys.objects where modify_date>='YourLastExtractDate'` it's not ideal becuase deletes will not get reflected and I don't believe ALL objects are in sys.objects. (triggers, pacakge bodies etc... not sure about)

Comment: @xQbert Sounds interesting, I'll definately have to play around with that.

Comment: Theres a script button in sql server, they click it, you get teh sql to do what they did in the gui. PS you do know this is going to go well wrong don't you?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson of course it will! at least 50 times before it works right. We finally got everything else working, this is one of the last steps.

Comment: Erm no more like once every 50 attempts it will work right. Probably because no one changed nuffin... :(

Comment: Out of interest, what terms were you searching for?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson Sorry, I can't remember what I originally searched for. I've been more successful finding tools lately searching for database compare, change data capture, and similar things to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are third party tools that are able to do what you asked for, specifically RedGate SQL Compare http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/ (Note, I am not affiliated with RedGate in any way).

Otherwise aside from creating ON INSERT/ON DELETE/ON UPDATE CASCADE triggers for every single table I don't really see a neat way of doing it.

Edit: Totally forgot about triggers and stored procs. They would not be covered by CASCADE triggers.